# OpenSSL 1.0.2h not accepting config parameters

Tags: openssl

I am trying to compile OpenSSL 1.0.2h from source in order to meet requirements defined by Common Criteria and for that i need to restrict certain class of cipher suites such as ECHDE, DHE, DSA, all TLS protocols except TLS1.2 and compile OpenSSL with the FIPS Object Module. I did the following:

```
root@cc3:/home/openssl#wget https://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz

root@cc3:/home/openssl#wget https://openssl.org/source/openssl-fips-2.0.12.tar.gz

root@cc3:/home/openssl#tar -xvf openssl-fips-2.0.12.tar.gz

root@cc3:/home/openssl#tar -xvf openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz

root@cc3:/home/openssl#cd openssl-fips-2.0.12 && ./config -d && make && make install

root@cc3:/home/openssl#./config fips no-camellia no-camelia \
no-tls1 no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-ecdh no-srp no-srtp no-dhe no-dh \
no-dsa no-psk no-idea no-seed no-rc4 no-deprecated no-des \
--prefix=/home/openssl/local && make depend && make && make install
```

however i am getting all sorts of errors while doing the above. For example, one error asks me to remove the `no-ecdhe` flag while another throws error if i add the `no-dh` flag.

Interestingly, some of the parameters such as `no-tls`, `no-camellia` are working if i use OpenSSL 1.0.2n but not all.

Can anyone help me in figuring out what i am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you compiling it on, and what's the compiler and its version ?

Comment: gcc version is: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 and i am compiling it on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

> ... however i am getting all sorts of errors while doing the above. For
>   example, one error asks me to remove the no-ecdhe flag while another
>   throws error if i add the no-dh flag.
>
> Interestingly, some of the parameters such as no-tls, no-camellia are
>   working if I use OpenSSL 1.0.2n but not all.
>
> Can anyone help me in figuring out what i am missing here?

I think there are three pieces to the puzzle. The first piece is, what `no-xxx` can you use to configure the library. I have never seen a list of available `no-xxx` options, but the answer is mostly shown below.

I can only say "mostly" because some things can't be disgorged even though there is an accompanying define. For example, things will break in a spectacular fashion if you try to use `no-aes` even though there is a `OPENSSL_NO_AES` define available somewhere.

As another example, some defines are special cases. I believe `OPENSSL_NO_STDIO` is used on iPhones and Windows Mobile devices. `OPENSSL_NO_STDIO` was needed to get through a compile on the platform due to missing headers and missing output devices, but it is not intended for general use.

```
$ grep -oIR 'OPENSSL_NO_[[:alnum:]]*' | cut -f 2 -d ':' | sort | uniq
OPENSSL_NO_AES
OPENSSL_NO_AFALGENG
OPENSSL_NO_ALGORITHMS
OPENSSL_NO_ARIA
OPENSSL_NO_ASAN
OPENSSL_NO_ASM
OPENSSL_NO_ASN1
OPENSSL_NO_ASN1T
OPENSSL_NO_ASYNC
OPENSSL_NO_AUTOALGINIT
OPENSSL_NO_AUTOERRINIT
OPENSSL_NO_BF
OPENSSL_NO_BIO
OPENSSL_NO_BLAKE2
OPENSSL_NO_BLOWFISH
OPENSSL_NO_BN
OPENSSL_NO_BUFFER
OPENSSL_NO_CAMELLIA
OPENSSL_NO_CAPIENG
OPENSSL_NO_CAST
OPENSSL_NO_CHACHA
OPENSSL_NO_CHAIN
OPENSSL_NO_CMAC
OPENSSL_NO_CMS
OPENSSL_NO_COMP
OPENSSL_NO_CONF
OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO
OPENSSL_NO_CT
OPENSSL_NO_DECC
OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED
OPENSSL_NO_DES
OPENSSL_NO_DEVCRYPTOENG
OPENSSL_NO_DGRAM
OPENSSL_NO_DH
OPENSSL_NO_DSA
OPENSSL_NO_DSO
OPENSSL_NO_DTLS
OPENSSL_NO_DTLS1
OPENSSL_NO_DYNAMIC
OPENSSL_NO_E
OPENSSL_NO_EBCDIC
OPENSSL_NO_EC
OPENSSL_NO_EC2M
OPENSSL_NO_ECDH
OPENSSL_NO_ECDSA
OPENSSL_NO_EGD
OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
OPENSSL_NO_ERR
OPENSSL_NO_EVP
OPENSSL_NO_FILENAMES
OPENSSL_NO_FIPS
OPENSSL_NO_FP
OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ
OPENSSL_NO_GOST
OPENSSL_NO_HASH
OPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS
OPENSSL_NO_HMAC
OPENSSL_NO_HW
OPENSSL_NO_IDEA
OPENSSL_NO_INLINE
OPENSSL_NO_KDF
OPENSSL_NO_LHASH
OPENSSL_NO_MD2
OPENSSL_NO_MD4
OPENSSL_NO_MD5
OPENSSL_NO_MDC2
OPENSSL_NO_MODES
OPENSSL_NO_MSAN
OPENSSL_NO_MULTIBLOCK
OPENSSL_NO_NEXTPROTONEG
OPENSSL_NO_OBJ
OPENSSL_NO_OBJECT
OPENSSL_NO_OBJECTS
OPENSSL_NO_OCB
OPENSSL_NO_OCSP
OPENSSL_NO_OPENSSLV
OPENSSL_NO_OSSL
OPENSSL_NO_PEM
OPENSSL_NO_PEM2
OPENSSL_NO_PKCS12
OPENSSL_NO_PKCS7
OPENSSL_NO_POLY1305
OPENSSL_NO_POSIX
OPENSSL_NO_PSK
OPENSSL_NO_RAND
OPENSSL_NO_RC2
OPENSSL_NO_RC4
OPENSSL_NO_RC5
OPENSSL_NO_RDRAND
OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
OPENSSL_NO_RIPEMD
OPENSSL_NO_RIPEMD160
OPENSSL_NO_RMD160
OPENSSL_NO_RSA
OPENSSL_NO_SAFESTACK
OPENSSL_NO_SCRYPT
OPENSSL_NO_SCTP
OPENSSL_NO_SECURE
OPENSSL_NO_SEED
OPENSSL_NO_SETVBUF
OPENSSL_NO_SHA
OPENSSL_NO_SIPHASH
OPENSSL_NO_SM3
OPENSSL_NO_SM4
OPENSSL_NO_SOCK
OPENSSL_NO_SPEED
OPENSSL_NO_SRP
OPENSSL_NO_SRTP
OPENSSL_NO_SSL
OPENSSL_NO_SSL2
OPENSSL_NO_SSL3
OPENSSL_NO_STACK
OPENSSL_NO_STATIC
OPENSSL_NO_STDIO
OPENSSL_NO_SYMHACKS
OPENSSL_NO_TLS
OPENSSL_NO_TLS1
OPENSSL_NO_TLS13DOWNGRADE
OPENSSL_NO_TLSEXT
OPENSSL_NO_TS
OPENSSL_NO_TXT
OPENSSL_NO_UBSAN
OPENSSL_NO_UI
OPENSSL_NO_UNIT
OPENSSL_NO_WEAK
OPENSSL_NO_WHIRLPOOL
OPENSSL_NO_WHRLPOOL
OPENSSL_NO_X509
OPENSSL_NO_X509V3
OPENSSL_NO_xxx
```

The second piece of the puzzle is, the FIPS canister is a sequestered object. You cannot remove unwanted things from it, like Diffie-Hellman or SHA-512. You have to live with any algorithm in the FIPS canister, so don't try to remove an algorithm.

If you manage to remove an algorithm from the FIPS canister then things could break in subtle ways. For example, you may have violated the build procedure so the resulting module is not FIPS validated. Or, you may get to runtime and `FIPS_mode_set` may return 0 because the module's checksum is bad.

The third piece of the puzzle is, the `OPENSSL_NO_*` are built dynamically from `no-xxx` using a Perl script. As far as I know there is no validation on them. This caused problems in the past when trying to disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 (and others). For example, using `no-ssl2` worked, but `no-sslv2` resulted in a silent failure because it was not a recognized option.

```
apps/progs.pl:2538:        print "#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SOCK\n${str}#endif\n";
apps/progs.pl:2644:        print "#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_" . uc($cmd) . "\n${str}#endif\n";
apps/progs.pl:2764:        print "#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_" . uc($disabler) . "\n${str}#endif\n";
apps/progs.pl:3227:        print "#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_" . uc($cmd) . "\n${str}#endif\n";
apps/progs.pl:3346:        print "#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_" . uc($disabler) . "\n${str}#endif\n";
apps/progs.pl:5089:        print "#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_" . uc($algo) . "\n${str}#endif\n";
apps/progs.pl:5214:        print "#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_" . uc($disabler) . "\n${st
```

---

It has been a while since I built the FIPS canister and I don't recall the procedural requirements. You might be interested in [FIPS Object Module v2.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf) User Guide for the exact procedure.

Comment: `openssl-x.y.zr` and `openssl-fips-x.y.z` will create two separate directories. It isn't a problem in OP's question. Secondly, `FIPS` canister libraries are independent and need to be built prior to the build of `openssl` libraries with `fips` option.

Comment: @iamauser - Thanks for the QA on the directories. However, there are no FIPS canister libraries. There are several artifacts from the procedure, but they don't include a library. Off the top of my head the artifacts are `fipscanister.o`, `fips_premain.c` and the SHA-1 fingerprint. Applications compile the C file and link directly against the object files.

Comment: thanks @jww for the detailed guidance.But yes to add upon iamauser's point, i am not trying to remove anything from the fips module since that would render its fips validation void as mentioned in the OpenSSL FIPS Guidance. I was trying to remove unwanted things from the OpenSSL Library. But thank you for providing a way to see all the available options that can be passed to OpenSSL config since that is not available anywhere else and see if it works for me or not. If not then i'll have to figure out another way to achieve the requirement. Thanks folks for your help!